# PHP Bracket Parsing Data

Tags: php, parsing

I'm trying to build my own little simple version of a page builder. I'm stuck getting the attributes and the values out of the code.

My goal is to build something that can take a code block like this below:

```
[section id="section-post" class="" data-id="43" data-var="mosa"] 
[container width="full"] 
[row] 
[block id="block-3 " class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 block-3-css"] 
[content id="3"] [special_heading type="h1" id="content-3" class=""]Welcome Title[/special_heading] [/content] 
[content id="content-4"] [divider class="divider line"][/divider] [/content] 
[content id="5"] 
[text]<p>This is a paragraph.</p>[/text] 
[/content] 
[/block] 
[/row] 
[/container] 
[/section]
```

And using php, find all brackets, identify them, pull out their attributes, and use them to be assigned as variables I can pass into functions to edit their attribute values in a form.

Can someone point me in the right direction? So far I'm at the point of being able to use this code below to identify the brackets and the content inside them.

```
$pattern = '/\[(\w+)([^\]]*)\]/';
if (preg_match_all($pattern, $page_data, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
    foreach ($matches as $match) {
        $blockType = $match[1];
        $attributesString = $match[2];

        echo "TYPE: $blockType <br /> ATTR: $attributesString <hr />";

        if ($blockType == "content") {

        }
    }
}
```

I get this output for each [] item:

TYPE: section
ATTR: id="section-post" class="" data-id="43" data-var="mosa"

TYPE: container
ATTR: width="full"

TYPE: row
ATTR:

TYPE: block
ATTR: id="block-3 " class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 block-3-css"

TYPE: content
ATTR: id="3"

TYPE: special_heading
ATTR: type="h1" id="content-3" class=""

I'm struggling to figure out what I need to do next to get something to work with assigning the attributes and their values. There might even be a better way to do this perhaps?

For example how do I properly get something like this?

$section_attr_id="section-post";

$section_attr_data_id="43";

Is there a better way that I could do instead of this?

Comment: why not use something like **xml** ? [official_documentation - xml-parse](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.xml-parse.php)

Comment: This looks relevant: [PHP: data-attributes to associative array using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29777579/2943403)  Your [mcve] should very concretely express what the desired output is -- from your supplied input string.

Comment: There’s no major advantage that I can think of for inventing a markup language to cover another markup language, at least with what you’ve shown. As noted, XML can be used, or even modern HTML with custom tags. Mixing markup will eventually lead to weird escaping and closing tag rules.